# Audio amplifier output bypass capacitor

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, audio, single-ended, class-a

I'm currently designing a single rail power supply audio amplifier and just wondering what the benifits are (if any) and if its worth including a film/poly capacitor in parallel with the large electrolytic capacitor.

**This is an example:**

[image]

In short, are there any advantages to the 10uF poly capacitor?
If so, what type would be best? MKP, MKS, PIO?

Comment: yes, electrolytic caps are far from perfect, especially at higher frequencies – however, if you're building a single-transistor feedback-less amplifier, you're most definitely not doing it because you're trying to build a hifi device, nor something that works like "real-world" audio amplifiers, so I'd honestly not bother.

Comment: I only included this image as a simple example circuit, my amp will have a preamp transistor stage with mosfet output and use global negetive feedback.

Comment: please don't post misleading examples! Instead, post your own amplifier. Whether or not it makes a difference depends on your use case, output impedance, frequency range, flatness and linearity requirements.

Comment: I did but in bold: This is an example:.

Comment: I know :) Not blaming you for a mistake! I just assumed the exemplarity of that example extended beyond the two caps into the complexity (or rather: lack thereof) of the amplifier circuit, that's why I wrote that first comment. I was mislead. But you could've helped to avoid that: by using an example that is actually very close to your actual amplifier circuit.

Comment: I see, no problem :)

Comment: That poly capacitor is in **parallel** with the output capacitor, not in series.

Comment: It depends if it is not a polymer electrolytic and the ESR/ load ratio

Comment: I agree with AG. Why have a distorted Amp just to save a few cheap parts and use an op amp to correct the low gain nonlinear distortion and use a bipolar supply

Comment: As stated. This is a very simple example circuit that is not mine that I will not use and is only ment to show a single supply amp.

Comment: When there is significant voltage across an electrolytic cap, you get a pretty sizable increase in nonlinearity. My guess is that since the ESL of the electrolytic is pretty high, the film cap keeps the impedance low and the voltage across the electrolytic low that you have minimal problems with rise in distortion in the high end.

Comment: Could just simply be because the ESL of the electrolytic is just too high to let high end AC through. Only way to find out is to test it, though you'll only find minimal changes (which sometimes matter, you just need special equipment to detect)